# Reset CSS hover dropdown with JQLite

Tags: html, css, angularjs, hover, jqlite

I'm currently in a project developing an Angular SPA that has dropdown menus in its main navbar. To get this effect, we are using CSS: hover selectors. The issue is that when an action is performed within this dropdowns we would like to close them without hindering the ability to open them again. For example, if a user opens a link within one of this dropdowns (internal link with ui-sref) he is then taken to this particular state, but the dropdown would still be visible until he moves the mouse outside it (and partially obscuring the new content shown). We would like the dropdown to be closed when an action within is performed and if the user would like to open it again, he would be able to hover the mouse again over the trigger.

We tried removing and re-adding classes (even after a timeout) but the dropdown reappears again.

Link to a Plunker with a setup similar to what we are trying to accomplish: https://plnkr.co/edit/qzQk4r2WQFhwsgUWug39?p=preview

And the relevant portions (Angular controller omitted as it has no content):

HTML:

```
 <div class="hoverable has-dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-trigger">Hover me!</button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    Dropdown content
    <button ng-click="buttonAction()">Action</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 1em;
}

.has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}

.has-dropdown .dropdown-trigger:hover + .dropdown,
.has-dropdown .dropdown-trigger + .dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by using ng-mousenter and ng-mouseleave and dropping CSS :hover rules. As everything is based on JS I can just trigger mouseleave when I want to close them.